# Request headers in Goliath middleware

Tags: ruby, goliath

I am writing own middleware for Goliath server.

How can I get request headers in "call" method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"call" method always return [status_code, headers, body] tuple, see example below:

```
class AwesomeMiddleware
  include Goliath::Rack::AsyncMiddleware

  def call(env)
    status, headers, response = super(env)
    [status, headers, response]
  end

end
```

Also checkout [AsyncMiddleware](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath/blob/master/lib/goliath/rack/async_middleware.rb) and [SimpleAroundwareFactory](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath/blob/master/lib/goliath/rack/simple_aroundware_factory.rb) in Goliath repository.